# Torsion tube and what it’s made of

Tags: garage-door

Is the torsion tube installed by a garage door installer any different than if I were to buy a 1” 16 gauge galvanized steel pipe from Home Depot or Lowe’s?  Or is that where they’re getting there torsion tubes as well?

Comment: Big box not always known for quality, maybe the same, maybe less quality.  There are different ways a pipe is made also, some pipe is stronger than another depending how it is made.

Answer (score 3):

Those are not the same things.

A garage door torsion tube is steel *tubing*. Unlike pipe, tubing is true to size: the outside dimension of a 1" steel tube is actually 1" (or maybe 0.995", but who's counting?). Also the wall thickness is likely to be 16 gauge (about 0.0595") for a narrow door or 14 gauge (0.075") for a wide door.

Steel *pipe* is often sized according to plumbing nominal sizes. The nominal 1" pipe actual outside dimension will be around 1.315", so none of the 1" garage door hardware will fit it.